# "Come to town" vs. "Come in town"

Tags: grammar, expressions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have to express that my friend is coming to visit me in my town and I'm waiting for him, what would be the differences and what would be the best between these two phrases?

> I'm waiting for my friend to come to town

or

> I'm waiting for my friend to come in town

Comment: _In town_ is a colloquial term for _in the town/city centre_  (it is used of London and other large cities). You would have to say _come into town_. But if you just mean that your friend will be arriving at the place where you live, use _to town_ or _to [name]_.